# Is there a difference in the repair processes of slow twitch vs. fast twitch muscle?

Tags: muscle, musculoskeletal-system

Working out, I noticed my fast-twitch-dominant muscles tend to get very sore and stay that way for hours to days, while my slow-twitch-dominant muscles tend to get sore briefly and recover quickly.

Is there a difference between the repair processes of slow twitch muscle vs. fast twitch muscle?

Comment: Seems better suited for fitness.se.